# Probability question: Statistics: What is the probability of B given A has occurred?

Tags: probability, statistics, self-learning

Question: 20% of gumballs in a machine are red. The other 80% are blue. 20% of the gumballs in the machine have dents in them. What is the probability of getting a dented gumball that is red?

My Approach:
We can call the probability of a red gumball P(r), the probability of a blue gumball P(b) and the probability of a dented gumball P(d).

We know P(r) and P(b) are independent as you can't have gumballs that are both red and blue.

The equation I want to use is P(r|d): (Join probability of r & d)/P(d)

So given that the gumball is dented, what is the likelihood it is red.

P(d) = .2
P(r) = .2

Where I am stuck is how to find the joint probability (or overlap) of dented red gumballs... (Since I am assuming we cannot say that blue and red gumballs are dented equally).

I feel like I should be factoring in P(b) somewhere to find that overlap of r & d, but I'm not sure how...

Any advice on how to find the joint probability of r & d is much appreciated!

(Additionally, the equation to find P(joint r & d)=P(d)*P(r|d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's let $B, R, \text{and } D$ denote the events that we draw a blue, red, and dented gum ball, respectively.

> We know $\mathsf P(R)$ and $\mathsf P(B)$ are independent as you can't have gum balls that are both red and blue.

Two events $A$ and $B$ are said to be independent if $\mathsf P(A\cap B)=\mathsf P(A)\cdot\mathsf P(B)$

But $\mathsf P(R\cap B)=0$ and $\mathsf P(R)\cdot\mathsf P(B)=0.2\cdot0.8=0.16$ so $R$ and $B$ are not independent.

In any case, the question asks for the probability of the gum ball being dented and red so we have

$$\mathsf P(D\cap R)=0.2\cdot 0.2=0.04$$

Comment: Indeed; the fact that the events cannot both occur means that they are *mutually exclusive* (aka *disjoint*); so the probability of the intersection is zero.  That is a rather different concept from *independence*; do not confuse them. @SadieL

Comment: Thank you! That is a great point and I completely had them mixed up in my head.

Comment: So a gumball being dented and a gumball being red are independent, but a gumball being red and a gumball being blue are mutually exclusive (aka disjoint)? (Just to confirm I have that correct in my head)